# Python list assignment index out of range error

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python and struggling with the following error message:

```
"products[j] = (num_list[(num_length - 2 - i)]) * 2
IndexError: list assignment index out of range"
```

when running the following code:

```
  def checksum():
    products = []
    i = 0
    j=0


    if num_length % 2 == 0:
        num_type = "even"
    else:
        num_type = "odd"
    print(f"DEBUG- {num_length}")
    print(num_list[2])

    while True:
        products[j] = (num_list[(num_length - 2 - i)]) * 2
        if num_type=="even" and (num_length - 2 - i) == 0:
            break
        elif (num_length - 2 - i) == 1:
            break
        i+=2
        j +=1




main()
```

The code seems to fail when running the first iteration of the following list assignment:

```
products[j] = (num_list[(num_length - 2 - i)]) * 2
```

however the index value seems valid?

Comment: first iteration should be  `products[0] = (num_list[(4 - 2 - 0)]) * 2`

Comment: A python list is not the same as a C array.  Space is not allocated.  You need to append to a list.  Once the entries are created, you can then assign to them using an index.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign anything to an empty list by index.
Perhaps, you want `products.append((num_list[(num_length - 2 - i)]) * 2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize products, you initialize it as an empty list. Since you never add any elements to the list when you go to set the jth element of products, you are referencing an index that doesn't exist. The following code shows a simple way of generating such an index error.

```py
p = []
p[0]
#IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you want to add an element onto the end of products you can do so using append.

```py
products.append((num_list[(num_length - 2 - i)]) * 2)
```

However if you want to set the jth element of products you will need to make sure that products contains at least j elements. If you know the maximum number of indices you'll want in products at the start you can generate an empty list with the following code.

```py
products = [None] * max_index + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers point out, it is not valid in Python to assign by index to an empty list in this way. In any case, you can approach this problem entirely differently in Python. It looks like you are iterating backwards through `num_list`, starting from the second-last number and skipping every other number, and the following would probably do what you want much more concisely without having to worry about indices:

```
def checksum(num_list):
    return [n * 2 for n in num_list[-2::-2]]

>>> checksum([1,2,3,4]) # returns [6, 2]
>>> checksum([1,2,3,4,5]) # returns [8, 4]
```